# how to convert a character type value ( this is the value: 1,54E+17) into a number in R?

Tags: r

I'm cleaning my dataset for my shiny project. Data comes from Kaggle:
https://www.kaggle.com/ravi72munde/uber-lyft-cab-prices

there's one col in the data frame called time_stamp. 
class(time_stamp) is factor and it has four levels:
 `1,54E+16` `1,54E+17` `1,55E+15` `1,55E+16` `1,55E+17`

I would like to convert these values into numbers, so in the end I could use epoch timestamp converter to turn them into normal time format.
My current idea is to convert it into character and then somehow turn them into numbers. I don't know whether this is realistic.

I want below result:

```
1,54E+16 --> 12:45pm 1 Dec. 2018 (for example)
```

Appreciate any help or suggestion.
Many thanks!

---

For more contextual info on my dataset. I have six digits for this col time_stamp.

```
dput(head(cab_rides$time_stamp)) 

c(1.54495e+12, 1.54495e+12, 1.54495e+12, 1.54495e+12, 1.54495e+12, 1.54495e+12)
```

Comment: How does `time_stamp` look in your input file before reading it to `R`?

Comment: Also, what does `dput(head(time_stamp))` output? Please add to your question text. The reason I ask is that R does not typically print out numbers to their full precision, so it's possible the "1,54E+16" is missing out on some precision that could distinguish one year from another. I suspect your data shows microseconds since 1970. 
 Try here: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: @JonSpring > dput(head(cab_rides$time_stamp))
c(1.54495e+12, 1.54495e+12, 1.54495e+12, 1.54495e+12, 1.54495e+12, 
1.54495e+12)

Comment: The good news is that you have six significant digits, not just 3. The bad news is they're all rounding to the same timestamp of 1544950000000, which is milliseconds since 1/1/70, and represents Sunday Dec 16, 2018 @ 8:46am GMT. But with that level of precision those could represent any times between around 7am and 10am that morning...

Comment: @JonSpring thanks a lot for your explanation. Now I understand much more than yesterday. The dataset I got from Kaggle, and I started a topic to ask the author for more info. https://www.kaggle.com/ravi72munde/uber-lyft-cab-prices/discussion/96231

Comment: @JonSpring One more question, in your example, the six digits I have represents Sunday Dec 16, 2018 @ 8:46am GMT which looks a very precise time point to me. How come it in fact  could represent any times between around 7am and 10am that morning. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Rounding! I'm saying that any time in that range will round to 1.54495e+12, aka 1,544,950,000,000. If I tell you I have a secret number where the closest multiple of 10 is 70, you don't know if my secret number is 65, 68.2434, 64.999, etc. It might be 70, but you don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Your factor does not have all the needed digits so you won't be able to make this conversion.

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2018-12-01 13:45"))
## [1] 1543689900
```

but all you have is:

```
1,54E+16
```

which is only the first 3 significant digits.

If you can get the data that produced the factor you may be able to recover the data to its full significance.

Comment: thanks for you answer. Used this as.POSIXct function and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I am the original author of the dataset. [G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516548/g-grothendieck) pointed out correctly that the dataset(maybe Kaggle or excel) format truncated the timestamp to just 3 significant digits. I have updated the dataset with overridden formats. I have also included the original .txt files(in zip) in case you face the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

The simtimer package has a function that may get you close enough, if the times are mini seconds since 1 Jan 1970. (Although note the caveat by Jon Spring in the comments).

```
library(simtimer)
xtimes <- c(1.54495e+12)     
simtimer::as.datetime(xtimes/1000, origin_date = as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC"))
#[1] "2018-12-16 08:46:40 UTC"

# going the other way
as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2018-12-16 08:46:40", tz = "UTC"))
#[1] 1544950000
```